# Is there a simliar function used to split one vec into two and keep the last elements?

Tags: vector, rust

We know that Vec provides split_off() function to split the slice into two. I wonder if there is a similar function that splits the original Vec, but keeps the back part and returns the front part as a new Vec directly?

Answer (score 3):

While a `vec.split_off_front(n)`, is not provided, you can use the more general `drain` instead:

```
vec.drain(0..n).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=62e3c63136167966f5df2b08f63e5ae2)

I do not know for a fact why `split_off` is part of `std`, but `split_off_front` is not. A possible reason I can imagine is that it cannot be done as efficiently. For a `split_off_front` to keep the elements after `n` in `self`, it would have to copy the elements in `0..n` to a new vector, *and then move the remaining elements from `n..` to `0..`*, because vectors *must always be filled from element 0*.

Contrary, `split_at` only needs to copy the elements its splitting off the original vector.

If you want to cheaply remove elements from the front of something, use a `Deque`.

Comment: It seems VecDeque.split_off() just keeps the first N elements too. I know the mem::replace() can process them cheaply. So I wonder why a symmetrical functon not provided.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `split_off_front` by combining `split_off` and `swap`:

```
fn split_off_front<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, at: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut split = vec.split_off(vec.len() - at - 1);
    std::mem::swap(vec, &mut split);
    split
}
```

I think this is in theory better than `drain` since only the elements at the end are moved.

---

You can also implement it with `split_off` and  `rotate_left`:

```
fn split_off_front<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, at: usize) -> Vec<T> {
    vec.rotate_left(at);
    vec.split_off(vec.len() - at)
}
```

I think this is in theory worse than `drain` since it requires moving the front elements twice.